# Copying an element (xsl:function) from the stylesheet to the "result" XML

Tags: xslt, copy, xls

First, I should say that I am a beginner in terms of XSLT.

Although the exact context may not be so relevant (and might be too confusing), I will provide it below.
I have a chained transformation, which looks like this:

1. `Input.xml` is the input file for this transformation, which is performed using `transform.xsl`. The result of this transformation is `output.xml`. `transform.xml` contains a classic custom `xsl:function`:

   ```
   xsl:function name="my:f"
        xsl:sequence select=".. xpath .."   
   xsl:function
   ```
2. The result from step 1 (`output.xml`) is, for step 2, a new transformer (`transform2.xsl`), which will be using some other XML input (let's say `input2.xml`).

What I would like to do is to copy the `xsl:function` **node** entirely (present in the `transform.xsl` in step 1) to the `output.xml`, so that it can be used in step 2.
No updates / changes are needed in this case for the `xsl:function` while copying it (just a simple node copy).
Note that I do not want to copy the `xsl:function` only when a given input element (from `input.xml`) is present. But rather, I want to copy it always, no matter what the `input.xml` is.

Now I know this can be made by having a separate file which contains my `xsl:function`, and then using `xsl:import` to include this file from both transformations (`transform.xml` and `transform2.xml`).

But I would like to know if there are other ways of accomplishing this (..without having a separate file where the function is declared / defined)?

Thanks in advance,

M.

Comment: @user414366: It's not clear why you want to built an XSLT 2.0 dynamically. In case you can't change the first stylesheet to isolate the function declaration in a common stylesheet module, you can import the first stylesheet into the second in order to use the function, taking care of apply templates through a `@mode` to avoid imported templates.

Comment: @Alejandro: I am using 3rd party style-sheets and I would like to keep the changes to the minimum. That is why importing the entire style-sheet (transform.xsl) from the other style-sheet (transform2.xsl) is something that would not be preferable in my case. Also, transform2.xsl is generated dynamically, so having the xsl:functions generated dynamically is not that bad in this case.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a function to be copied to the output -- it can (and should!) just be imported as part of a stylesheet module. Copying the function is negative work -- it results in lesser performance, more moving parts (code) and possibilities for errors and significantly affects the readability, understandability and maintainability of the product. If I am given this bad code, one of the first refactorings I'd do will be removing the copying code and placing the function into a separate stylesheet module that is imported. You need to learn, especially if you are a beginner!

Comment: @Dimitre: Copying code is something that I also do not encourage. After more thought I decided to drop the common function in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the stylesheet document using `document('')` so doing e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:function"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>
```

should copy any `xsl:function` elements in the stylesheet to the result tree.

**[edit]**
After the edit it seems you want to copy a function of a certain name: if you want to copy the function of certain name then you could do e.g.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:function[
        resolve-QName(@name, .) eq QName('http://example.com/ns', 'f')]"/>
```

where `f` is the local name of the function and `http://example.com/ns` is the namespace the function is defined in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Martin! You answered so fast.. and so good :) I did not know that you can use document() in that way to get to the document node. I learned something today :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document()` built-in function which wil return the stylesheet document for an emtpy URI. Then you can just copy the element to the output.

Comment: Lucero, I would like to thank you, too! But Martin replied first, so I would flag his answer this time.